# SMTP service (gmail) is not working in opencart. its returning an error every time

Tags: php, opencart

I am going to use gmail in opencart as SMTP but its returning error in in every page where email is to sent some where. Like when new user register instead of going to account page or when someone submit contact form the folloing error appears.

`Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection refused) in /public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 153Notice: Error: Connection refused (111) in public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 156`

Following are the configuration I have done in opencart mail setting.
[image]

I have allowed unsecure appes and gone through the google DisplayUnblockCapcha.
but its still not working.

any help please...!!

Comment: check your gmail account you probably received mail about security issues, check here https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: no email i have recieved.. and its not working at all.

Comment: same error.. any other solution.

Comment: did you enable use low security apps ?

Comment: yes I have enabled that.

Comment: wait while to let it take effect, could take hour or two

Comment: Why are you using `ssl://` in your mail server line? Just set the server to smtp.gmail.com and use port 465. 

(Unless that's necessary for Opencart 1.5, I've only used 2 and later).